# pass ILogger as constructor argument to a class in a referenced class library project

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.2

I have a class library project which i am referring from my main console application (The class i am using is `ProcessService`). 
If the constructor would take only ILogger as an argument like this:

```
public ProcessService(ILogger factory)
    {

    }
```

And then i register it in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` Like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IProcessService, ProcessService>();
```

It works fine. The problem is that i need to pass other then ILogger another argument which i take from appsettings so the constructor of the class looks like this:

`public ProcessService(int period,ILogger factory){}`

And then im trying to register it like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IProcessService>(new ProcessService(refreshInterval*1000,ILogger logger));
```

But i have to pass an initialized logger and its not correct. 
What is the way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I believe you can achive what you want by using `services.AddSingleton<IProcessService>(x => new ProcessService(refreshInterval*1000, x.GetRequiredService<ILogger>()));` Otherwise, please let me know and I will remove my vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. @smoksnes

Comment: please mark as duplicate if you believe that the solution given in the other answer effectively answered your question.